# How do I validate fields with the required attribute or not null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, if-statement

I am doing some validation and can't get my `if` statement to work. I want to validate fields with a data type and the required attribute. Or if a field is not null?

My if statement:

```js
if (typeof $(this).attr("data-type") != "undefined" 
        && typeof $(this).prop("required") != "undefined"
        || typeof $(this).prop("required") === true
        || $(this).val() != "") {
    // Doing stuff
}
```

The HTML input:

```html
<input type="text" name="Consignee" id="text" data-type="text"
       placeholder="Consignee" required>
```

Comment: Select elements using `$(":input[required]")`

Comment: Can you show me this in my if statement please? im really struggling

Comment: Can you show us complete example ?

Comment: No really sorry its to large :( that is just the outer IF then all the validation happens inside. I am using a $.each to loop through all the fields FYI

Comment: "I want to validate fields with a data type and the required attribute. Or if a field is not null?" that literally doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no require typeof.
try this query ...

```
if ($(this).attr("data-type") != "" && $(this).prop("required") != false && $(this).val()!="") {}
```